# Quarkus CDI context with Kotlin coroutines

Tags: quarkus

I'm trying to offload some Hibernate / Hibernate Search calls to a different thread, but I'm getting errors suggesting CDI is not set up properly in that thread.

I've looked at the guide at https://quarkus.io/guides/context-propagation, but there's no reference to kotlin coroutines.

Is there any way to do this context propagation with coroutines?

I'm using

```
val entityReferences = withContext(Dispatchers.IO ) {
    //hibernate code here
}
```

```
javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getDelegate(ClientProxies.java:40)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.RequestScopedSessionHolder_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(RequestScopedSessionHolder_ClientProxy.zig:42)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.RequestScopedSessionHolder_ClientProxy.getOrCreateSession(RequestScopedSessionHolder_ClientProxy.zig:102)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.acquireSession(TransactionScopedSession.java:104)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.createQuery(TransactionScopedSession.java:376)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.ForwardingSession.createQuery(ForwardingSession.java:188)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.ForwardingSession.createQuery(ForwardingSession.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.Session_5b93bee577ae2f8d76647de04cfab36afbf52958_Synthetic_ClientProxy.createQuery(Session_5b93bee577ae2f8d76647de04cfab36afbf52958_Synthetic_ClientProxy.zig:927)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to attach the request scoped context to the thread by creating a custom coroutine context.

```kotlin
class RequestContextElement(private val controller: RequestContextController) : ThreadContextElement<Boolean>, AbstractCoroutineContextElement(Key) {
    companion object Key : CoroutineContext.Key<RequestContextElement>
    override fun updateThreadContext(context: CoroutineContext) = controller.activate()
    override fun restoreThreadContext(context: CoroutineContext, oldState: Boolean) = controller.deactivate()
}
```

Inject the `RequestContextController` to the bean that is creating the coroutine.

```kotlin
@Inject
protected lateinit var requestContextController: RequestContextController
```

Then add the custom context to the coroutine context

```kotlin
val entityReferences = withContext(Dispatchers.IO + RequestContextElement(requestContextController)) {
// Hibernate code
}
```

I used the following resources

- https://codingwithmohit.com/coroutines/custom-coroutine-context-uses-cases/
- https://rmannibucau.metawerx.net/cdi-2.0-request-scope-controller.html

The first resource might also be some help with propagating transactions if necessary.